# Automatically add the user in a cell in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When one cell (Data) is edited, I'd like to automatically update another cell with the name of the user who edited the Data cell.

So far I found the script below that I was able to copy and use and that I'd like to amend to ensure I have both the user (activeuser?) and the last modified date. 
I hope you can help.

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 

  event.activate(form);
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();

  var dateCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(index,dateCol);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "MM-dd-yy HH:mm");

  lastCell.setValue( date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that the above scripts gets you the last modified date i.e the date variable and as for the user the event info has an attribute user that can be used i.e event.user should give the one who edited the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on user information being passed by the event (documentation suggests this will always return the owner of the spreadsheet anyway) you might try using the following in addition to your code above:

```js
var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
sheet.getRange(index, (dateCol + 1)).setValue(user);
```

This is the solution I use to identify editing users and it works well for me. This does however make the assumption that the editing users are logged into a Google account.